# Error Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

Tags: sendmail

Trying to send out a simple data set from SQL. I have used this before on another server in the past with no issue. My script

```
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = '**** DB Mail',  
    @recipients = '*****@*****.com', 
    @subject= 'Customer',
    @query = N'select CustNum,Name,Addr_1,Addr_2,Addr_4,City,State,Zip,County,Country
    from _customer',  
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

I have tested and verified that SQL mail itself works just fine. (SQL 2016)

the error that I get

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

Completion time: 2024-02-26T10:15:21.7817853-08:00

I have tried everything that I have seen online

Thanks,
Sean

checked my permissions, checked that SQL sent mail works. It's a simple script and works fine by itself.